# Selection/Unselection for recursive childs nodes on clicking the top most node - highchecktree Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select/unselect the recursive child nodes on clicking the top parent node before expanding all the child nodes ?

***Issue:*** If we select/unselect the top most node of highcheck tree, it will select/unselect resp. the nodes upto 2nd level only. So,If there exist the 3rd level, selection/unselection will **not** be maintained for the same and for the further levels too, on clicking the top parent node **unless we expand all the nodes.**

***Reason for the Issue:*** What I found is, Initially it creates html for only upto 2nd level of the parent. And further if we click on the child, then it will create the next level (if exists).Thus the selection/unselection is not maintained if we click on top most node before expanding all the nodes.

[Highchecktree JS plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Checkbox-Tree-View-highchecktree.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for the same.
We can achieve the task by creating all nodes initially by expanding all the nodes and then collapsing the same using the code below:

```
    //for creating all nodes initially
    function createAllNodesInitially(node) {
        /*To display whole High Check Tree expanded Initially*/
        setTimeout(function(){$('.collapsed').click() }, 1000); 
        for(var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
            if(node[i].children != undefined){
                createAllNodesInitially(node[i].children);
            }
        }
        /*To display whole check tree collapsed after creating all nodes Initially */
        setTimeout(function(){$('.expanded').click() }, 1000); 
    } 
    createAllNodesInitially(settings.data);
```

***Just add this code to highchecktree.js.***

***Explaination:*** This will expand all the nodes,which will internally create all the nodes and then collapse all the child nodes. And thus now the selection/unselection will be automatically maintained for all the recursive child nodes on clicking the top most node.

This will be executed once when the highchecktree is created (i.e., Initially).

**Note:** If you want to initally show all the nodes ***Expanded***, just remove/comment following line from the code:

> setTimeout(function(){$('.expanded').click() }, 1000);

Hope this will help you all.